# Como fazer "Aspas Semânticas" com a tag <q>, mas ela estando com um font-family diferente

Tags: html, css, semântica

A pergunta é bem simples e objetiva, eu quero ter um estilo de fonte para o parágrafo e outro estilo que fonte para as aspas, porém quando eu coloco o conteúdo entre a tag `<q>` o que está dentro pega o `font-family` do `<q>` e perde o font-family do `<p>`.

Para fica mais claro veja o exemplo.

```css
p {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: serif;
}
q {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <q>adipisicing elit</q>. Ipsum, quas.</p>
```

A parte do texto que está envolvida pelas tag `<q>` fica com o font-family diferente do `<p>`, mas eu quero só as aspas e não o texto inteiro de dentro da tag

Não quero usar aspas direto no corpo do texto, tem que ser com a tag `<q>`, isso não teria valor ok `... "texto" ...`

***Como posso resolver esse problema de forma semântica usando a tag `<q>` e de forma que eu possa reutilizar em outras partes do texto?***

Comment: Eu não sei o que isso tem haver com semantica e sinceramente fiquei com dificuldade de entender o enunciado ... mas supeito que você deseja  isto `q { quotes: "«" "»" "‹" "›"; }` (é só um exemplo), entendi certo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Na verdade é que teoricamente a ta `<q> seria a tag para quote correto?`Para o leitor de tela entender que está entre aspas e não usar "texto" e sim <q>texto</q> entende. Acho que posso ter me expressado mal, o que quero dizer é que seria obrigatório usar a tag `<q>` para colocar o conteúdo dentro. E tem mais a ver com o font-family e não com o tipo de aspas.

Comment: Não tem como afirmar que um leitor de tela vá reconhecer `<q>` ou `"` ou `'`, isso é especulação, existem diferentes leitores de telas, com funcionamentos variados, suporte ou falta de suporte para certas tags HTML. Eu poderia "presumir" que um bom leitor de tela reconhece todos (`<q>`, `"`, `'`), porque a ideia é de fato ler o texto e nem todo dev é um bom dev para compreender as necessidades de pessoas com deficiencia visual.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é um ponto de vista bem interessante! Até pq alguns leitores são pagos, e as vezes quem não quer comprar a versão mais nova que de suporte as coisas mais novas pode ficar sujeito a esse tipo de "detalhe".... *(não que a tag `<q>` seja nova)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um jeito de fazer isso é definindo o `font-family` diferenciado somente para os pseudo-elementos `after` e `before` da tag `q`:

```css
p {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: serif;
}

q:before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
q:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <q>adipisicing elit</q>. Ipsum, quas.</p>
```

Com isto, somente as aspas terão a `font-family` diferente. O conteúdo que está dentro de `<q>` fica com a mesma fonte do `<p>`.

---

Lembrando que se o `q` tiver regras específicas, os pseudo-elementos também as terão:

```css
p {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: serif;
}

/* q com regras específicas, serão aplicadas em before e after */
q {
  color: red;
}
q:before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
q:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <q>adipisicing elit</q>. Ipsum, quas.</p>
```

Neste caso, o `before` e `after` herdam a cor vermelha definida em `q`. Caso isso não seja o desejado, bastaria definir uma cor diferente nos pseudo-elementos:

```css
p {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: serif;
}

/* q com regras específicas */
q {
  color: red;
}
q:before {
  content: open-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* sobrescrever a cor definida em q */
  color: black;
}
q:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* sobrescrever a cor definida em q */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <q>adipisicing elit</q>. Ipsum, quas.</p>
```

---

Referência: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes)

Comment: Agradeço pela contribuição